# PHP not retrieving radio input value

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I'm having a real problem with retrieving the value of a radio button using PHP . . . I have two radio buttons as such:

```
<input name="admin" type="radio" value="1" />Yes
<input name="admin" type="radio" value="0" checked />No
```

And a conditional PHP statement checking to see if PHP can retrieve any data from it:

```
if(!empty($_POST['admin'])) {
    // do stuff
}
else {
   echo "Value not set";
}
```

the problem is that PHP can seem to return a value for the radio buttons if "yes" is selected, but not if "no" is selected, I've tried removing the "checked" portion, to no avail. I just can't get it to retrieve the "0" value whatever I try.

I remember using PHP arrays to name checkboxes, but this shouldn't be needed for radio buttons surely, as only can be selected at any one time?

Or does PHP just have a problem returning radio buttons with a value of 0?

Or am I doing something horribly wrong without realising it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP function empty will return false for 0, NULL, "", and others.

Quoting from php.net:

> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

All of these will return (false) therefore nullifying the execution of your if statement.

You will have to modify your condition to reflect a value depending on what you wish to accomplish.

Good luck!

Comment: so would isset() work for checking the value for "0" in this situation?

Comment: Exactly :) But you would also have to check if the value is 0, isset would work even if the value was 1 or any other value. Use a double condition like what Hendrik Richter said. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again, always amazed at the speed and quality of responses on here!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that empty() treats zeros as empty values, no matter if it's a number 0, or a string '0'. So, instead of using empty() use isset() and/or direct checks, e.g.

```
if (isset($_POST['admin'])) {
```

or

```
if (isset($_POST['admin']) && $_POST['admin'] == 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the zero is your problem. Try setting them to "Y" and "N" and you should see that the N value comes through. This is because 0 is an empty value in PHP.